# two functions - getting char and work on pointer

Tags: c, pointers, char

in C:
Im trying to write 2 functions one is getting from the user a line (string) and sending it to another function that remove (if exist) blank space from start of the string.

I am trying to make the "remove_space" function work on pointer, alter it by making it point to the continue of the string without the space.

for example: 
lets say the user type:
"   hi123"
and i save this string in some pointer
i want to send this pointer to "remove_space" function and make the pointer point at "hi123" without the spacing starts...

for now.. i have some problems with the pointers from what i see.
this is what I wrote:

```
void remove_space(char** st1)/**function to remove space**/
{
    char* temp_st = strtok(st1, " ");
    strcpy(st1, temp_st);
}

void read_comp(void)
{
    printf("read_comp FUNCTION\n");
    char* st1; /**read the rest of the input**/ 
    fgets(st1,30,stdin);
    remove_space(st1);
    printf("%s\n",st1);
}
```

Comment: Once you've accepted some previous answers, consider splitting this into two questions. You already have two functions, and should be able to approach each function separately.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't allocate memory to store a string in `st1`.

```
char st1[30];
```

Also, you don't need a `char**` here.

```
void remove_space(char *st1)
{
    char *temp_st = strtok(st1, " ");
    strcpy(st1, temp_st);
}
```

Comment: Surely `remove_space` needs to receive `char*`. Otherwise I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Right, `char**` is useless here.